# Div fill the ion-item

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am using ion-list and ion-item to repeat the data, the problem that I am facing now is I can't make the div table to fill inside ion-item. I want the table to fill just like ion-option button.

I want the table just like the black rectangle in the attached image.
Thank you in advance

```
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" href="#/app/event/{{item.id}}" >

    <div class="row">
        <div id="div1" class="col color1">Event {{ item.id }}</div>
        <div id="div2" class="col color2">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>

    <ion-option-button class="button-calm icon ion-android-favorite" ng-click="favorite(item)">
        &nbsp Favorite
     </ion-option-button>
     <ion-option-button class="button-positive icon ion-android-notifications" ng-click="notify(item)">
        &nbsp Notify
   </ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Example

[image]